# Метод friends.areFriends не работает (VK API)

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://userapi.com/js/api/openapi.js?49"></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
  VK.init({apiId: 3012101, onlyWidgets: true});
</script>
VK.Api.call("friends.areFriends",{uids: '176326390'}, function(data) {
var Count = data.response.length;  // узнаем количество друзей
 
            for (var i=0; i<Count; i++)
            {
                document.write(data.response[i].uid);
            }     
});
```

Не работает. Говорят ошибка `data.response.length;` и `document.write(data.response[i].uid);`. Помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Для отладки используйте console.log()

В вашем примере перед тем как узнать length сделайте console.log(data)

Если у вас chrome, используйте "инструменты разработчика" (CTRL+SHIFT+I -> вкладка Console)

[image]

Comment: А у вас случайно не белая страница появляется?

Comment: белая, белая...
http://i060.radikal.ru/1209/10/acd9c079c690.png

Comment: 1. не делайте document.write - делайте innerHTML в созданный тег. 
2. У вас еще и проблема с контактиком. Для того чтобы работать с друзьями, нужны права, которые вы должны запросить до того как выполнить friends.areFriends

Comment: http://s017.radikal.ru/i430/1209/0a/22aa89c7bbd7.jpg

Comment: а нет вроде разобрался

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+I - можно просто F12.